# How to get each pixel position (Coordinate) of a Hollow Character drawn using Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am using UIView subclass to draw an alphabet using Core Graphics.Using this code only hollow characters are drwan(By Making the stroke color- black color).Here I need each pixel(Coordinate) position of the character.Please give me an idea how I will get each pixel point(Only the black point's pixel value) of the hollow character.

***Source Code:***

```
/*UIView Subclass Method*/

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
      //Method to draw the alphabet
      [self drawChar:@"A" xcoord:5 ycoords:35];
}
-(void)drawChar:(NSString *)str xcoord: (CGFloat)x ycoord: (CGFloat)y
{

    const char *text = [str UTF8String];//Getting the alphabet
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSelectFont(ctx, "Helvetica", 40.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFillStroke);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);//to make the character hollow-Need only these points
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);//Fill color of character is clear color

    CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformMake(
                                                    1.0,  0.0,
                                                    0.0, -1.0,
                                                    0.0,  0.0);//Giving a transformation to the alphabet

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, xform);

   CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, x, y, text, strlen(text));//Generating the character
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there's convenient method to set the fill and stroke color:

```
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
```

either that or use `CGContextSetGrayFillColor` and `CGContextSetGrayStrokeColor`.

---

As for your problem, to get pixel information, you have to use a `CGBitmapContext`. You can get the bitmap by `CGBitmapContextGetData`. Suppose you declare an RGBA bitmap, the bitmap data will be arranged as

```
RGBA_at_(0,0)  RGBA_at_(1,0)  ...  RGBA_at_(w,0)  RGBA_at(0,1)  RGBA_at_(1,1) ...
```

therefore, you can scan linearly for any target color values and determine the black pixels.

---

Please note that `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is not necessarily a `CGBitmapContext`, so you *should not* apply `CGBitmapContextGetData` on it. Instead, you have to create your own bitmap context with `CGBitmapContextCreate`, draw the text onto this bitmap context, obtain the CGImage result by `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, and finally draw this CGImage onto the UIContext.